# Unity3d- How can I check if my character is in air for 2 seconds?

Tags: unity-game-engine, seconds

I'm using a raycast to determine if my player is in air or not

How can I check if my character is in air for 5 seconds before switching to another state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add two new variables.

```
bool InAir;
float InAirTimer;
```

When you do the raycast, set InAir to true if you're in air, false if you're not. Then in update, do this:

```
if (inAir) { inAirTimer += Time.deltaTime; }
else { inAirTimer = 0; }
if (inAirTimer >= 5) { /* Here is where you do something */ }
```